# Cannot access network from LXD container created by the ubuntu-sdk

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, lxd

I've created an LXD armhf image from inside the ubuntu-sdk, and I can launch it successfully. However, this image is not able to access the network: any execution of `apt-get install ...` will fail with similar errors:

```
 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/libs/libsdl2/libsdl2-dev_2.0.2+dfsg1-6ubuntu2_armhf.deb  
    Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/libs/libsdl2-mixer/libsdl2-mixer-dev_2.0.0+dfsg1-5_armhf.deb  
   Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
```

There are no `ifconfig`, `route`, `wget` or even `ping` commands inside the image, so I have no clue on how to debug this. Note that this happens only inside the LXD container: from my machine, I can access internet without any issues.